# How to update a child node in Firebase without over-writing other nodes

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

```
 func like() {
    if let indexPath = clickedLike {
        let selectedRow = indexPath.row
        var CurrentLikes =  posts[selectedRow].likes
        CurrentLikes += 1
        let update = ["likes": CurrentLikes]
        
        postRef.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            //get the key for the exact post that is liked
            let likesKey = snapshot.key
            // save number of likes to database
            Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(likesKey).updateChildValues(update)
    })
        
    }
}
```

So i have a bunch of posts that in the tableview each post is in a tableview cell that has a like button. When i press the like button the func like() is called. The problem i am having is that when i like a post it updates the value of the likes for all the posts in the table view instead of on just the post that i liked.

My firebase database looks like this (link below). The likes are saved in the likes child for each post which has an auto-id.

[image: Firebase database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code indeed will update the `likes` for each child node of `postRef`.

If you only want to update the `likes` for a single child node, you will need to know the push key of that child node, typically by storing that somewhere when you first read the data.

For example, if you'd store the `key` of each child `DataSnapshot` in the `posts` array as `key`, you could do:

Then you can increment the like count without first reading it with:

```
func like() {
    if let indexPath = clickedLike {
        let selectedRow = indexPath.row
        var key = posts[selectedRow].key
        var CurrentLikes =  posts[selectedRow].likes
        CurrentLikes += 1
        let update = ["likes": CurrentLikes]
        
        postRef.child(key).updateChildValues(update)        
    }
}
```

---

Or you can use the atomic increment operation, to make this secure against multiple users liking at (almost) the same time with:

```
func like() {
    if let indexPath = clickedLike {
        let selectedRow = indexPath.row
        var key = posts[selectedRow].key        
        postRef.child(key).child("likes").setValue(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1))        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Frank!! The first suggestion worked like a treat!

Comment: Good to hear @CodingForFun333 .    Don't forget to accept the answer once the system allows that, so that others know the problem is solved.